# C# craps simulation

Tags: c#, loops, if-statement, random

I have seen questions related to Craps, but they were related to python and Java. I hope someone familiar with C# can help me. The code below is meant to simulate the game of craps. The code mostly works, except for one issue.

I suppose I should briefly explain the game. Two 6 sided dice are rolled. If the result is a 7 or 11. The player or "shooter" wins automatically. If a 2, 3, or 12 is rolled, the shooter loses automatically. However, if another number is rolled, that number becomes the "point". The shooter rolls again until either they roll the point again or a 7. If the point is rerolled the shooter wins. If a 7 is rolled, this time it is a loss.

So, the problem is that this code still gives wins or losses automatically for 2, 3, 11, and 12 after the first roll. For example: The shooter rolls a 6. 6 becomes the point and the shooter rolls again. If the shooter rolls a 3 this code marks this result as a loss when it should just keep rolling until a 6 or 7 is rolled. This incorrect end happens whenever a 2, 3, 11, or 12 is rolled after the first roll. Any help on correcting the logic of this code would be greatly appreciated. Thanks Also, I hope this question is formatted correctly. Please let me know if it is not.

```
class Craps
{
    const int dieSides = 6;

    int roll;
    //const int repeatGame = 1000;

    Random random = new Random();

    public void RollDice()
    {
        int die1 = 0;
        int die2 = 0;

        die1 = random.Next(1, 7);

        die2 = random.Next(1, 7);

        roll = die1 + die2;
        //Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
    }

    public void PlayCraps()
    {
        RollDice();
        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);

        int gameStatus = 0;
        int point = roll;
        int numRolls = 1;
        if (roll != 7 || roll != 11 || roll != 2 || roll != 3 || roll != 12)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("The point is: {0}", point);
        }
        while (gameStatus < 1)
        {


            if (roll == 7 || roll == 11)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                gameStatus++;
                break;
            }
            else if (roll == 2 || roll == 3 || roll == 12)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("You lost.");
                gameStatus++;
                break;
            }
            else
            {

                while (point != roll || roll != 7)
                {
                    RollDice();

                    if (roll == point)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
                        Console.WriteLine("You won!");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                        break;
                    }

                    if (roll == 7)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
                        Console.WriteLine("You lost");
                        numRolls++;
                        gameStatus++;
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        numRolls++;
                        Console.WriteLine("The shooter roled: {0}", roll);
                        break;
                    }

                }

            }

        }
        Console.WriteLine("This game was {0} roll(s)", numRolls);
    }



    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Craps NewGame = new Craps();
        NewGame.PlayCraps();
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: step through your code with VS excellent debugger and watch what it does

Comment: You need to add a variable that keeps track of the current point and check it that is matched first. If there is a current point you skip to the next roll. If no current point then check for 2/3/11/12

Comment: your last break is triggereing the 3 behavior. Once there is a point, if the roll is not 7 or the point you are breaking out of that inner loop

Answer (score 0):

User pm100 commented saying that the final `break` returned the code back to the outer loop and that this was causing the error. Removing this fixed the issue described in my question. There may be other errors or ways to improve this code, but that comment solved the particular focus of this question.